# Hide address bar on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5

I've seen plenty of scripts on the web about hiding the address bar by scrolling down to hide it etc. But I noticed that Apple actually hide it completely as in make it disappear!

http://help.apple.com/iphone/5/interface/ on your iPhone you will see the bar removed...

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're doing `event.preventDefault()` on the `touchstart` event and handling scrolling in their own code.

Comment: How does that hide the address bar?

Comment: They use the same scrolling down technique you're mentioning (you can see this as the page loads the first time, the address bar is briefly visible). Preventing `touchstart` just prevents you from scrolling it *back* into view.

Answer (score 1):

They're not removing it. It's behaving in the same way as every other webpage does in Mobile Safari. The difference appears to be in the way they're displaying the page itself. If you tap on the Status Bar while looking at that webpage the navigation bar appears for you.

I switched my useragent on Safari to Mobile Safari and it looks like they're not actually scrolling the page when you swipe, but have a div setup with overflow:hidden; and you're scrolling inside that div instead of the page itself.

(Edit: This appears to be in addition to hiding the bar by scrolling down the page)

Answer (score 0):

To hide the address bar, use jQuery and execute the following on document load:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('html,body').scrollTop(0)
};
```

The address bar will disappear and will reappear only if the user touches the screen to make it reappear.